# MicroFrontend with flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture, frontend, micro-frontend

I have a simple application which would turn into a quite complex one, I want to know if theres a possible way to achieve the same.

Followed Package:

- https://pub.dev/packages/microfrontends

Followed different Blogs:

- https://dev.to/netfirms/flutter-approach-in-micro-frontend-term-17f3
- https://medium.com/@carlos.vicens.alonso/building-a-flutter-app-that-fits-in-with-your-micro-services-strategy-417a72e81732
- https://flutterawesome.com/a-package-to-speed-up-the-creation-of-micro-frontendor-independent-features-structure-in-flutter-applications/
- https://medium.com/bancolombia-tech/micro-apps-in-flutter-does-it-makes-sense-d86cd0838b47

It's either outdated or doesn't provide concrete example.

Anyone who has managed building micro-frontend or has an idea or direction for me to follow to create widgets in an app and dynamically reuse the widgets in different apps, would be helpful.

**What I need ?**

Build widgets in one app and dynamically use those widgets in another app

Comment: Why cant you return in your bodya listview builder, for a List<Widget>, where you store all your widgets? You can even make a map like {'widget':..., 'height':..., 'width':...}and resolve is while building the listview

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this [LinkedIn article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/introduction-micro-frontend-flutter-dwi-kurnianto-mulyadien/).

Basically you can use the Flutter package approach to separate your features to different repositories / projects. Each package will have it's own `pubspec.yaml` file, so different teams will be able to work on different packages while managing a "core" package.

It good to mention that you won't be able to deploy specific features, but you will have to deploy the whole project with the updated feature package.